# Invoking python passing a path to search for modules to import

Tags: python, python-import

How can I achieve something like `$ python --search-for-includes=/foo/bar /home/user/x/script.py`,where `script.py` has `import something` and `something.py` is in `/foo/bar`,
**without editing an environment variable**, and without editing `script.py`.

I tried `python -c 'import sys; sys.path.append("/foo/bar")' /home/user/x/script.py`, but it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable in following way:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar:$PYTHONPATH python /home/user/x/script.py
```

Comment: without environment variable

Comment: @asdqwe, how about `PYTHONPATH=/foo/bar python /home/user/x/script.py` ? It will not overwrite environment variable of the current shell.

Comment: @PM2Ring, I updated the answer code not to clobber existing `PYTHONPATH`. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @asdqwe: I assume you have some reason not to use the standard mechanism that Python uses to locate modules in packages. But why don't you want to use PYTHONPATH?